# Break down comma separated values into children nodes

Tags: python, echarts

I have a list which is of this format:

```
[[2020,
  'September',
  9,
  '12:00',
  '1',
  28,
  'Breaking',
  7.0,
  'Request Body Type Changed,API Path Removed Without Deprecation,Request Property Removed,Response Property Became Optional,Response Success Status Removed']]
```

This is the hierarchy I have created with the list:

```
              {
                'name': '12:00',
                'children': [
                  {
                    'name': '1',
                    'value': 28,
                    'children': [
                      {
                        'name': 'Breaking',
                        'value': 7.0,
                        'children': [
                          
                        ],
                        'hidden_children': [
                          {
                            'name': 'Request Body Type Changed,API Path Removed Without Deprecation,Request Property Removed,Response Property Became Optional,Response Success Status Removed',
                            'value': 7.0,
                            'itemStyle': {
                              'color': '#ad213e'
                            },
                            'label': {
                              'rotate': 0
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        'itemStyle': {
                          'color': '#ad213e'
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
```

However as you can see I have all the children in a comma separated format. What I want to do this put them as separate children in the hierarchy. Which means instead of one `hidden_children` node for `Breaking` parent node, there will be `4 hidden_children`.

The expected hierarchy is:

```
    {
        'name': '12:00',
        'children': [
            {
                'name': '1',
                'value': 28,
                'children': [
                    {
                        'name': 'Breaking',
                        'value': 7.0,
                        'children': [],
                        'hidden_children': [
                            {
                                'name': 'Request Body Type Changed',
                                'value': 7.0,
                                'itemStyle': {'color': '#ad213e'},
                                'label': {'rotate': 0}
                            },
                            {
                                'name': 'API Path Removed Without Deprecation',
                                'value': 7.0,
                                'itemStyle': {'color': '#ad213e'},
                                'label': {'rotate': 0}
                            },
                            {
                                'name': 'Request Property Removed',
                                'value': 7.0,
                                'itemStyle': {'color': '#ad213e'},
                                'label': {'rotate': 0}
                            },
                            {
                                'name': 'Response Property Became Optional',
                                'value': 7.0,
                                'itemStyle': {'color': '#ad213e'},
                                'label': {'rotate': 0}
                            },
                            {
                                'name': 'Response Success Status Removed',
                                'value': 7.0,
                                'itemStyle': {'color': '#ad213e'},
                                'label': {'rotate': 0}
                            }
                        ],
                        'itemStyle': {'color': '#ad213e'}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am not sure how can I split the string to graph them out as different children nodes.

This is my code for creating this hierarchy:

```
def create_hierarchy(api1):
    root = {"name": "root", "children": []}
    for row in api1:
        year, month, day, time, info_version, api_changes, type1, count, content = row + [None] * (9 - len(row))
        year_node = None
        for node in root["children"]:
            if node["name"] == year:
                year_node = node
                break
        if not year_node:
            year_node = {"name": year, "children": []}
            root["children"].append(year_node)
        month_node = None
        for node in year_node["children"]:
            if node["name"] == month:
                month_node = node
                break
        if not month_node:
            month_node = {"name": month, "children": []}
            year_node["children"].append(month_node)
        day_node = None
        for node in month_node["children"]:
            if node["name"] == str(day):
                day_node = node
                break
        if not day_node:
            day_node = {"name": str(day), "children": []}
            month_node["children"].append(day_node)
        hour_node = {"name": str(time), "children": []}
        day_node["children"].append(hour_node)
        info_node = {"name": info_version, "value": api_changes, "children": []}
        hour_node["children"].append(info_node)
        if type1:
            type_node = None
            for node in info_node["children"]:
                if node["name"] == type1:
                    type_node = node
                    break
            if not type_node:
                type_node = {"name": type1, "value": count, "children": []}
                info_node["children"].append(type_node)
            if type1 == "Breaking":
                type_node["hidden_children"] = []
                type_node["itemStyle"] = {"color": "#ad213e"}
            if content:
                if "," in content:
                    content_list = content.split(", ")
                    for content in content_list:
                        content_node = {"name": content, "value": count}
                        if type1 == "Breaking":
                            content_node["itemStyle"] = {"color": "#ad213e"}
                            content_node["label"] = {"rotate": 0}
                            type_node["hidden_children"].append(content_node)
                        else:
                            type_node["children"].append(content_node)
                            type_node["itemStyle"] = {"color": "#ad213e"}
                else:
                    content_node = {"name": content, "value": count}
                    if type1 == "Breaking":
                        content_node["itemStyle"] = {"color": "#ad213e"}
                        content_node["label"] = {"rotate": 0}
                        type_node["hidden_children"].append(content_node)
                    else:
                        type_node["children"].append(content_node)
                        type_node["itemStyle"] = {"color": "#ad213e"}
    return root["children"]

hierarchy1 = create_hierarchy(api1)
```

`api1` here is the name of my list.

Does anyone have suggestions or ideas how I could do this?

Comment: Shouldn't `'name': '09:46',` be `'name': '12:00',`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, by mistake I uploaded the wrong hierarchy, thanks alot for pointing it out!

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do. I see the comma-separated list beginning with `Request Body Type Changed`, but your desired result doesn't have them in separate elements. Is that not really the desired result?

Comment: I want to split that list into multiple `hidden_children` nodes, which means `Request Body Type Changed`, `API Path Removed Without Deprecation`, are all different child nodes. So instead of one, for the list I sent, `Breaking` will have `4` children

Comment: But you said you want to create it "as follows" and they're not different child nodes in that. Post the actual desired result.

Comment: Should they be in `children` or `hidden_children`?

Comment: I have added the expected output

Comment: Looks like you just need to use `split()` to split the comma-separated string, and a list comprehension to create the `hidden_children` list.

Comment: I am not sure how to add it in the hierarchy code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to create the list of dictionaries for each element of the comma-separated string.

Avoid all the duplicate code in `if` statements by using a variable to hold the key, either `children` or `hidden_children`.

```
            if content:
                children_key = "hidden_children" if type1 == "Breaking" else "children"
                content_list = content.split(",")
                type_node[children_key] = [
                    {"name": c, "value": count, "itemStyle": {"color": "#ad213e"}, "label": {"rotate": 0}}
                    for c in content_list]
```

There's no need for testing whether comma is in `content`, because `split()` will return a list of one string if it doesn't exist, and looping over that will return a list of one child.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: `split(", ")` should be `split(",")` since you don't have spaces after the commas. I mistakenly copied that from your code.

Comment: I've tested this, I think it works.